# Angular - using ngFor to create an accordion menu. Needs to auto-close and open another upon click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

Angular Material accordion component is in my angular project.

I'm using an ngFor to loop through the information of `menuItems` and make a new expansion panel for each item. I have two components, and I inject my menu Item into the html which has the panels.

Right now, I have

```html
<mat-accordion *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems">
  <confmenu menuItem={{menuItem}}></confmenu>
</mat-accordion>
```

And in my confmenu (child template):

```html
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]= "expandedItem === menuItem" (opened)= "newExpandedItem()">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{menuItem}}
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>
                {{menuDescription}}
            </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        <mat-form-field class="mat-expansion-panel-body">

          <mat-select  (change)="selectConfig($event.value)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of menuOptions" [value]="option" (click)="selectConfig(option)">
              {{option}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

</mat-expansion-panel>
```

in the child's component I have

```
expandedItem:string;


newExpandedItem(){
      this.expandedItem = this.menuItem;
    }
```

the ts as a whole is

```js
/** @title Basic menu */
@Component({
  selector: 'confmenu',
  templateUrl: './confmenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confmenu.component.scss']
})
export class ConfigurationMenu implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() menuItem: string;
expandedItem:string;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() { 

//first menu item
this.expandedItem = "firstItem"
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    //blank for now
  }

  selectConfig(value:string){
    this.selectedConfig = value;

  }

    newExpandedItem(){
      this.expandedItem = this.menuItem;
    }


}
```

Any ideas on how to make it so that the panels close on click of another panel? Right now, they are all staying open upon clicking another.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for the same

Comment: One way is to maintain a panel `index` at each child components by passing it from the `*ngFor`. And maintain a `currIndex` property aswell. Emit the index from the component that is expanded, all the other components will be subscribed to this event and close automatically, since their `index` will not match the `currIndex`. You can utilize service to emit the events or else parent component will also do.

Comment: @AmitChigadani awesome. i think i understand. So in my parent i do :

```
            <mat-accordion *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems; index as index">
                <confmenu menuItem={{menuItem}} [index]="index"></confmenu>
            </mat-accordion>
```

and in my child ts i do       @Input() index: number;

then, what do i do in my child html template? confused about index vs. menuItem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to maintain a panel `index` at the child component level by passing it from the `*ngFor`. And maintain a `currIndex` property aswell within each child component. Then you can expand/collapse the panel if `index` matches `currIndex`.

child.comp.ts

```
export class ConfigurationMenu {

  @Input() index = -1;
  @Input() currIndex = -1;

  @Output() currIndexChanged : EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  onExpandCollapseChanged() {
    // if its already open then emit -1 and close the panel, else open the panel
    const i = this.index === this.currIndex ? -1 : this.index
    this.currIndexChanged.emit(i)
  }
}
```

parent.comp.ts

```
export class ParentComponent {
  currIndex = -1;
}
```

parent template

```
<mat-accordion *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems; let i=index">
  <confmenu [index]="i" [currIndex]="currIndex" menuItem={{menuItem}} 
   (currIndexChanged)="currIndex=$event"></confmenu>
</mat-accordion>
```

child template

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]= "index === currIndex" (opened)= "onExpandCollapseChanged()"
(closed)="onExpandCollapseChanged()">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
.......
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to actually do it through using a service. In my service i had:

```
    private expandedMenu = new BehaviorSubject('');
    openedMenu = this.expandedMenu.asObservable();




changeExpandedMenu(menu: string){
        this.expandedMenu.next(menu);
    }
```

In my component, i had

```
this._menuService.openedMenu.subscribe(expandedMenu=> this.expandedMenu = expandedMenu);
```

onInit and the function

```
    newExpandedItem(menuItem: string){
      this.expandedMenu= menuItem;
      this._menuService.changeExpandedMenu(this.expandedMenu);
    }
```

therefore, in my template, i just did

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]= "expandedMenu===menuItem" (opened)="newExpandedItem(menuItem)">
```

thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: Nice! Using services is also a better approach.